# Example of a compact module which is not finitely generated

Tags: ring-theory, modules, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

Let $R$ be a ring and $M$ be an $R$-module.

> *Definition:* $M$ is called *compact* if $\text{Hom}_R(M,-)$ commutes with direct sums, that is, if for any set $I$ and any $I$-indexed family of $R$-modules $\{N_i\}_{i\in I}$ the canonical map of abelian groups $$\bigoplus\limits_{i\in I}\text{Hom}_R\left(M,N_i\right)\longrightarrow\text{Hom}_R\left(M,\bigoplus\limits_{i\in I} N_i\right)$$ is an isomorphism.

*Example:* Any finitely generated $R$-module is compact.

> *Proposition:* If $R$ is Noetherian, any compact module is finitely generated.

I'm looking for an example witnessing that this is not true without $R$ being Noetherian:

> ***Question:*** What is an example of a ring $R$ and a compact, but not finitely generated $R$-module?

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111472/reference-request-compact-objects-in-r-mod-are-precisely-the-finitely-presented) seems to say that regarless of $R$ being Noetherian, compact $\iff$ finitely presentend $\implies$ finitely generated. But the two definitions of "compact" are different, are they equivalent?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: Yes, I suspect the compactness property I'd like to understand is strictly weaker than the one in the link you posted - but thanks for that, it's good to have a reference for the case of preservation of arbitrary directed limits.

Comment: Yes, in [the linked MO question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/59282/sums-compact-objects-f-g-objects-in-categories-of-modules) they are called "sumpact" (sum compacts), and it is stated that it's a weaker property than "compact" ($\hom(M,-)$ commutes with filtered limits). In fact [this answer](http://mathoverflow.net/a/94442/36146) by Jeremy Rickard answers your question, I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/94442) by [Jeremy Rickard](https://mathoverflow.net/users/22989/jeremy-rickard) answers your question:

> A fairly simple explicit example of a "sumpact"<sup>*</sup> module that is not f.g. is as follows.
>
> Let $R$ be the ring of functions from an uncountable set $X$ to, say, a field $k$. Let $M$ be the ideal of functions with countable support.
>
> Then it's very easy to show that $M$ isn't f.g., and fairly easy to show that it is "sumpact", using no set theory beyond the fact that a countable union of countable sets is countable.

<sup>*</sup> A sumpact module is a $R$-module $M$ such that $\hom_R(M, -)$ commutes with arbitrary direct sums – what is called "compact" in the question.

Comment: This is a CW answer so that the question doesn't remain unanswered, but if someone is willing to post a different answer that's fine by me. I have to admit I don't understand what the downvote is for?

Comment: I don't understand either @ downvote... Thank you very much for your help! (+1 of course)

Comment: @Najib Idrissi Could you describe explicitly the example please? I asked the related question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1187256/a-property-for-finitely-generated-modules