# A property for finitely generated modules

Tags: modules, direct-sum, finitely-generated

Consider the folowing property for an $R$-module $M$ (where $R$ is an associative ring with identity):

For each family $\{M_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in I}$ of $R$-modules and each homomorphism $f:M\to \bigoplus_{\alpha\in I}M_{\alpha}$, there exists a finite subset $J$ of $I$ such that $\text{Im}f\subseteq\bigoplus_{\alpha\in J}M_{\alpha}$.

Every finitely generated $R$-module $M$ satisfies the condition.

My QUESTION is:

Is this condition a characterization of finitely generated  $R$-modules, or is there an example of an $R$-module which satisfies the property but it is not finitely generated?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1148219/example-of-a-compact-module-which-is-not-finitely-generated

Comment: Thank you @Hanno, the property posted in my question is weaker than the property of being sumpact, because it states that the induced homomorphism is an epimorphism (not an isomorphism). But the example works as well.

Comment: hello @Hanno, I've been thinking about that example, but I can't figure out how it works. Can you answer the question explicitly?